# getArguments method of MessageSourceResolvable

Tags: java, spring

what is the sequence of arguments of `getArguments()` method of 
 **MessageSourceResolvable** interface with `@Size` annotation???

**Employee.java**

```
public class Employee {

private int id;
@Size(message = "length exceeds : name",max = CommonConstants.NAME)
@NotBlank(message="should not be null")
private String name;
@Size(max = CommonConstants.ROLE, min=1, message = "length exceeds : role")
private String role;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}
}
```

**EmployeeController.java**

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(EmployeeController.class);

private Map<Integer, Employee> emps = null;

@RequestMapping(value = "/emp/save.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveEmployeeAction(
        @Valid Employee employee,
        BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        logger.info("Returning empSave.jsp page");

        List<FieldError> errorslist = bindingResult.getFieldErrors();
        for (FieldError error : errorslist) {
            Object[] args=error.getArguments();
            System.out.println();
            for (Object object : args) {
                System.out.println(object.toString());
            }
        }
        return "empSave";
    }
    logger.info("Returning empSaveSuccess.jsp page");
    model.addAttribute("emp", employee);
    emps.put(employee.getId(), employee);
    return "empSaveSuccess";
  }
}
```

**CommonConstants.java**

```
public class CommonConstants {

public static final int NAME=4;
public static final int ROLE=2;

}
```

**input**

```
name="xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz"  
role="CEO"
```

**console output**

```
arg : org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [employee.role,role]; arguments []; default message [role]
arg : 2
arg : 1

arg : org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [employee.name,name]; arguments []; default message [name]
arg : 4
arg : 0
```

In the 1st output `2` is the `max` and `1` is the `min` parameter value of `@Size` annotation of **role**(see Employee.java)
and
In the 2nd output `4` is the `max` and `0` is the `min` parameter value of `@Size` annotation of **name** (see Employee.java)

Now the question is in which sequence i've got these arguments from `getArguments()` method of **MessageSourceResolvable**??

Does this sequence is same even i changed sequence in parameter??

Comment: It is very hard to understand without any context , Can you Please post what are you trying, what is the issue, or Post any code